# Comfortable Working of Selection Tool

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, shortcut

After changing the hotkey "Selection" tool began to work by clicking the <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> (Select/deselect). I'm just fine with that, but there is one catch:

If use the Border Selection outside the object (<kbd>LMB</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>) this tool is working correctly, but if using it  within a object, before created selection is cleared.

For example:
If I need to add additional polygons to the current selection

1)
[image]

2)
[image]

What I need to change or add to this tool works correctly within the current object and  active selection is not reset?

Current HotKey:
[image]

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with your border select key definitions, its probably the `Select/Activate` operator that is resetting your selection. Try change it to either to a `Mouse Release` event or to `Extend Selection` by default. This is very likely a limitation of the current system I've bumped into in the past myself

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Would you like to post that as an answer? R_M_S, when he does, make sure you accept it.

Comment: Certainly, posted bellow.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably nothing wrong with your *Border Select* key definitions, its probably the *Select/Activate* operator that is resetting your selection.

Try change it to either to a `Mouse Release` event or to `Extend Selection` by default, so there's no conflict and starting a border select won't unintentionally trigger the colliding operator.