# Enhanced border select hotkey

Tags: interface, workflow, customization, selection-tools

Two border selecting questions:

1)
The proper method to add border select as the mouse point click drag and selection method with shift add or remove item capability.

Added an entry with selection to the mouse (as mentioned in the forum) but this doesn't work properly. When clicking an item it sometimes jumps to another nearby item.

2)
Is it possible to change the selection method when you are border selecting?

When your are border selecting an item:
How to at border select tweak scroll up to activate lasso select and scroll down to active circle select?

Comment: Please keep only one question per post, ask as many separate posts as necessary. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66231/border-select-how-to-disable-the-selection-of-closest-vertex-to-the-frame/66238#66238

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65248/comfortable-working-of-selection-tool/65252#65252 Border select is a modal operator, you can't change selection mode unless you end that operator first and then start a new one.

Comment: @ Duarte Farrajota Ramos - first message
As requested before this message is already a split up of several hot key questions. There  is a limit of posting a message. You can only post a message every 40 minutes. If I split it up even more it will take too long to post all the questions. 

@ Duarte Farrajota Ramos - second message
Thanks, Clear answer. [You can call this threat closed.]

Answer (score 1):

You are describing three different selection methods. Each method works independent of each other, you only use one at a time.

[Border select](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#border-select) - press <kbd>B</kbd> and then dragging with the <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> will give you a selection rectangle that will select items within it. Holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> when dragging will deselect items within the border. Dragging with the <kbd>[image: MMB]MMB</kbd> will also deselect. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> will cancel the operation.

[Circle select](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#circle-select) - press <kbd>C</kbd> and you are presented with a circle around the cursor, items within this circle when <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> clicking will be selected. Holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> while clicking or clicking with the <kbd>[image: MMB]MMB</kbd> will deselect items. The <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> and the numpad <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> can be used to change the size of the selection circle. Circle select stays active until you cancel by clicking <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[Lasso select](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#lasso-select) - holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> when dragging the non-selecting mouse button (that is left click by default but is right click if you are using select with left) will activate a lasso that will select items within the drawn region. Holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> while dragging will cause items to be deselected.

Note that border and circle select always select with the left mouse button and cancel with the right, this does not change with the Select With Left/Right setting.

The border and lasso select are temporary and only last for one mouse click while the circle select stays active until canceled.

All three add/remove to the existing selection, they do not replace the selection. You can use them repeatedly to gradually increase the selected items. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all before starting one of the above to create a new selection.

Comment: Thanks for the explained answer. This does not answer my question/feature request directly. It is a nice overview and good explanation of selection methods and how to best use it. But this not always works for me. (That's why I asked) (In an effort to simplify it, combing some similar (selection) methods would make things easier, but this is another work-flow and approach)

Anyway thanks again.

Comment: The main point is you don't "combine" the selection methods, you use one at a time, even if each is only adding one vertex to the selection and you use each multiple times in any sequence. Even if you use box, lasso, box, box, lasso, circle to select the verts you want, you are using each in a sequence and not combining them.

Comment: The point of combining has nothing to do with the functionality of the specific methods. Although combining has more to do with similar methods. (Combining is the wrong word used => it's reconfiguring the hot key's/the HID (human input method)) It is more like an alternative work flow where hot keys are ´simplified'. (The approach like you mentioned, which i do understand, is multiple hot keys each for every specific method. The good side of this is that you have direct access to specific methods the negative side is that it might clutter/overload the amount of hot keys.) ...

Comment: ... I prefer few main hot keys over a lot of different hot keys which has specific functionality and used once in a while. The one or the other does not always works best but combining hot keys shares both good aspects of both approaches.

Comment: * Going a bit off topic * (In the same domain on a larger level)

(It is said that if you want to get the most benefit from blender you have to customize blender to your need/your work flow. < See the questions asked)

(On the other side it is also said (mostly for understanding quickly tutorials and learn blender) it is good to learn and keep the default input layout)